# When does a coclass have to be properly defined in an .idl?

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, com, atl

I've created several shell extension classes (e.g., a property handler, drag-and-drop handler, context-menu handler, etc.), and when adding the necessary interfaces to the C++ classes themselves, I've never bothered changing the coclass definitions in the .idl file.  So the coclass definitions in the .idl file just have the ATL project defaults, i.e.:

```
coclass DragDropHandler
{
    [default] interface IDragDropHandler;
};
```

Nonetheless, as long as the actual interfaces and COM map are implemented properly in the C++ class, Explorer is able to load and call my shell extension classes just fine.

But just recently I created a class that implements a custom interface.  I didn't have the coclass entry in .idl file correct, and `CoCreateInstance` failed with `E_NOINTERFACE`.  Upon fixing the .idl file so that the coclass had the correct interface, it wound up working.

So I was wondering why the .idl file might not have to be updated and correct for shell extension classes, whereas when instantiating a class on my own, it had to be right.  Does one approach involve using a type library, whereas the other doesn't?

Comment: Some dev tools depend on the .TLB (here you're using CoCreateInstance yourself, so it's not the case) but in general, it's more a problem with proxies (cross apartment / out-of-process scenarios). A proxy can read the TLB to determine what interfaces it must marshal.

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah yes.  I was creating my class out of process, whereas shell extensions are loaded in process.  So that probably explains the difference.